# Unable to override display:none in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this case I can not set the element state to visible:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #elem {display:none}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="elem">.......</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("elem").style.display="";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it works only when I set display to "block".

In this case it works:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="elem" style="display:none">.......</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("elem").style.display="";
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My interest is to make it work in first case without setting "block".

Comment: means the above thing **{display:none}** is not working, it not reading even **{display:block}** , because writin block or not wont create any difference, it'll display it as usual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why do you want to use inline styles instead of css classes?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #elem.hidden {display:none}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="elem" class="hidden">.......</div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("elem").className = '';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `.style.display` property to `""` will remove any inline style from the element. The previous value in the cascade will then apply.

In this case, there is no inline style to start with, and the `"none"` value is already received from the cascade.

You could set the value to [the `"initial"` keyword](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-cascade/#initial), but you may find browser support lacking.

---

You've abstracted whatever the underlying problem that you are trying to solve by modifying the `display` property away, but there is a good chance that you would be better off with:

```
#elem.JSOnly {display:none}
```

with:

```
<div id="elem" class="JSOnly">
```

and

```
document.getElementById('elem').className = ""
```

or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("elem").style.display="block";
```

Answer (score -3):

You also use jQuery, like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('#elem').css('display','');
</script>
```

You want to also add jquery library.